# openerp 7.0: How to hide submenus from Settings?

Tags: odoo

I don't want the HR Guys to see anything but the submenu Users within the main menu settings.

Therefor I removed "500 - Settings" in the group "Administration / Access Rights" and added "4 - Settings / Users".

It seems that I misunderstood something, because the tap "Settings" disappears completely.

Could anybody give me a hand with this? Do i need to add some user rights? Is there even a possibility to do that via Groups and Menu Items?

Greetings,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

The way to "hidde" the other menus is to seperate the users menu from the settings as technical user in Settings -> User Interface -> Menu Items.

Afterwards connect the new users main menu with the groups which need accses to the users menu.

Important: dont forget to give the access rights so they can manipulate data

Greetings

Martin

Comment: Or Just create a new one with same content and add it to another menustrukture

Answer (score 0):

create a new group, specify this group to the settings menu and users menu along with their default groups.Then provide this group to your "HR Guys"

Comment: If i do that all other submenus like Modules or Configuration will also appear. The settingsmenu has al other menus as submenus